# What does it mean to "bounce a(n) __ off" someone?

Tags: idioms

I recently tried to use the expression "bounce an *opportunity* off someone" in writing, but using it seemed awkward to me. The expression "bounce an *idea* off someone" felt much more comfortable, but it didn't convey what I meant to get across. I believe the expression means something like "I want to conversationally determine what someone's thoughts are about a particular idea", but I'm not even sure if that interpretation is correct.

1. What does it mean to bounce an idea off someone? Does the expression have a known origin?
2. Can I only bounce "ideas" off someone? Can it extend to other concepts (such as "opportunities")?
3. Is there a better way to idiomatically express the phrase "bounce an opportunity off someone", in the sense of "I want to conversationally gauge someone's level of interest in a particular opportunity"?

Comment: It's just a metaphorical usage. You "throw" an idea at someone, and note how it "bounces" off them. If it doesn't bounce *at all*, your idea ***fell flat***, which probably means it's a *bad* idea. You don't "bounce an opportunity" off someone - you ***sound them out** about it*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll look into the "sound out" usage soon.

Comment: @Downvoter: any reason for the anonymous downvote? Would be more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bouncing an idea off a person means requesting that the person give a somewhat immediate response or gut reaction to the idea. Metaphorically speaking, the response bounces back to you right away.

It is rare to find the actual origin of a new word or a new sense of a word. I checked various standard references but found no known origin for this metaphor. The earliest use I found in print is the book *U.S. International Business and Governments* by Jack N. Behrman (McGraw-Hill, 1971):

> The existence of these associations … permits government officials to know that, at almost any critical time, they can find an audience against which to *bounce an idea or a new policy*.[¹](http://books.google.com/books?id=aP_sAAAAMAAJ&q=%22bounce+an+idea%22&dq=%22bounce+an+idea%22&hl=en&sa=X)

The quotation above shows that it is possible to bounce things other than ideas off someone. I think there is nothing wrong with “bouncing an opportunity” off someone. Alternately, you could “bounce *an idea for* an opportunity” off them, or “bounce a *business proposal* off them” if that is an appropriate restatement.

Comment: +1: To be honest, I actually like the first answer better, but I really appreciate the legwork you put in, and I feel it somehow better answers every aspect of the question.

Comment: Here are [a few earlier ones](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ideas+to+bounce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TAzlUOfwFaS-0QWy04GYDg&ved=0CCwQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1960&tbm=bks) going back to at least 1946.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Excellent. With some wheedling and coaxing of Google Book Search, I have come to believe most of those are excerpts or reprints of an article in *Forbes Magazine*, "So You're Going to a Convention" by Norman G. Shidle. The year of publication might be 1946.

Comment: Millbrook Round Table, Thursday, May 17, 1956, p. 6:
"Ideas have much in common with rubber balls. The way they bounce depends on where they start from, the force with which they are thrown, dropped tossed or pushed, the character of the surface on which they hit.—Norman G. Shidle"

Comment: Beaver Valley Times, Saturday, April 21, 1956, p. 8
"Ideas have much in common with rubber balls. The way they bounce depends on where they start from; the force with which they were thrown, dropped, tossed, or pushed; the character of the surface on which they hit; the "texture" of the ball or idea itself, the ambient temperature in which the bounce takes place. All of these influence the bounce of a ball – and the rebound of an idea.—Norman G. Shidle"

Comment: These quotations are later, but I suppose they are taken from one of Mr Shidle's books on salesmanship and that he may actually be the originator (or at least the popularizer) of the metaphor. He was quite popular in his day.

Comment: @MετάEd: Nah - I'm sure it would have been commonplace by the time Shidle wrote it. You might think this 1930 [an idea bounced into his mind](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22idea+bounced+into+his+mind+so+alarming%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is a "different" sense, but this 1944 [we just stay here and bounce ideas back and forth for hours](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22just+stay+here+and+bounce+ideas%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is pretty much OP's usage. I think it would hardly need a "populariser", being such transparent imagery.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Bounce an idea off someone](https://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bounce+an+idea+off+someone___1)

> *informal*, share an idea with another person in order to get feedback on it.
>
> Metaphorically, I know of nothing else that can be “bounced” off someone.
>
> You might, *“**run** an opportunity by someone”*.

Comment: +1, especially for your third point. I'll have to find more ways to use that expression.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I only bounce "ideas" off someone? Can it extend to other concepts (such as "opportunities")?

No, you cannot – not unless you want to get some strange looks. It seems like only [ideas](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bounce%20an%20idea,bounce%20a%20question,bounce%20a%20thought,bounce%20an%20opportunity,bounce%20a%20proposal&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) get bounced off people – not questions, thoughts, opportunities, or proposals:

[image]

(I thought this was an interesting question, though, which is why I decided to check.)

Comment: +1: Thanks for the link with data. And I'm actually quite used to saying many funny things that earn me strange looks from people, so maybe I'll be checking in here more often than not going forward. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @Peter: BTW, nothing wrong with using unusual language in conversation. If someone told me, "I want to bounce an opportunity off you," and I had a quizzical look, and that person continued, "Why not? If you can bounce an idea, you should be able to bounce an opportunity, too, right?" I'd be impressed with their original thinking. (I mean, I wouldn't use that during a job interview, but there are times where such quirky language can be memorable and appropriate.)