# Is there an idiom for someone who nods and listens usefully?

Tags: idioms, listening

I had a coworker who would occasionally say something like, "I can't solve this problem. Would you play Wooden Indian for me?" (referring to the carved figures that used to stand outside cigar stores) His meaning was: I need to talk through this with a live person who will listen and ask appropriate questions, and I think I could see the solution myself at that point.

I often need this, too, as I process problems best aloud; but I don't want to run around asking coworkers to be "wooden Indians" as this seems racially insensitive. Is there another idiom for this role?

Comment: isn't that just having a conversation with somebody?

Comment: Side note, but tell your coworker to just get something to talk to. It's the process of talking through a process that helps, not having someone listen.

Answer (score 85):

In software engineering, a person that agrees to listen for no purpose other than to allow a problem to be expressed verbally is commonly referred to as a "rubber duck" or "rubber ducky".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: This is still a metaphor and it's domain-specific, so I think this is the best answer.

Comment: But in British English "Ducky" or "Duckie" can be a term of affection, so be careful who you use it with.

Comment: As a programmer, I commonly use the expression "Rubber duck" (as it's referred in the wikipedia link"), but I've never heard it used as "rubber ducky". Also, using "duck" would get rid of @Dragonel 's concern.

Comment: @xDaizu - I've heard it as "rubber duckie" here in the states, but "rubber duck" *is* more common. However, either way, it seems in practice to be an IT-specific usage (though it's not *inherently* so), and the question doesn't specify a domain.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - the question doesn't *explicitly* specify a domain, but as it was asked by "Sarah the Coder" for a phrase to be used at work, I'm going to guess the domain is appropriate. :)

Comment: @Jules - entirely possible; likely, even - but I'll still stand by my non-domain-specific answer _because_ it's generic, and _not_ potentially misinterpretable as derisive or insulting (which I've encountered with the "rubber duck" usage, which is why I don't use RD with the humor-impaired).

Comment: @Jules - excellent sleuthing, and you didn't even need a skull :)

Comment: I have never heard this terminology so either it's outdated or is specific to some domain bound SW engineering culture. Sounding board on the other hand is much more general and I've seen it being used more frequently.

Comment: Not common enough to be worth putting as an answer, but sometimes the rubber ducky is called a "teddy bear", after the policy in a University IT lab of having to explain a problem to a teddy bear before being allowed to ask a tech for help, as the teddy solved a high percentage of problems at that stage. It later turned out that Turing had a similar, but not quite the same, use of teddy bears, having a teddy that he would address lectures to when working on them.

Comment: The "Rubber Duck Debugging" process explicitly states that the programmer is supposed to explain the problem/process to an inanimate object. The question explicitly asks for the idiom/phrase for a PERSON who listens to the problem and will respond with suggestions when appropriate. This answer, therefore, is incorrect.

Comment: @vynsane my colleagues and I regularly refer to each other as rubber ducks in this context, so I disagree that this can only be applied to an inanimate object. We are talking about usage, rather than a narrow definition found in a specific document.

Comment: @AaronD - while you and your colleagues may use the phrase when referring to each other, if the person being spoken to isn't playing the part of an inanimate object and is instead interjecting suggestions or questions, they aren't actually a rubber duck. People misuse words and phrases all the time, usually through memetic mutation, but that doesn't mean the original intent or definition of the word or phrase has changed. While the definition may be narrow, it can be [found far and wide](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubber+duck+debugging).

Comment: @xDaizu: Unfortunately it wouldn't get rid of xDaizu's concern entirely, as "duck" is equally a term of endearment in [parts of the UK](http://www.thepotteries.org/dialect_qa.html#Where_). But I don't think there's really much reason to worry, since (a) "rubber duck" isn't a term of endearment, (b) the context would make the intended meaning clear anyway, and (c) as a term of endearment it's mild and inoffensive anyway, so the chances of causing offence are small even if it were misinterpreted.

Answer (score 77):

I’ll often tell a colleague ***“Hey {name}, I need a sounding board”*** or ***“Hey, {name}, let me bounce this off you”***.

[Merriam-Webster (1c)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sounding%20board) defines ***sounding board*** as “a person or group on whom one tries out an idea or opinion as a means of evaluating it”, but the actual usage in this context is more accurately described by [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sounding%20board) - “A sounding board is a good listener, and either confirms what they hear or offers an opinion when [what] they hear is "off key".”.

***Bouncing an idea off ...*** has been the [subject of a question here on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/what-does-it-mean-to-bounce-an-off-someone), and was answered well. [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bounce_an_idea_off) simply defines it as “Share an idea with (someone) in order to refine it.”

Both usages should be considered informal/colloquial, just as are “wooden Indian”, “rubber duck”, and “nodding dog” mentioned in this question and its various answers.

A third phrase that I’ll occasionally use, in a semi-humorous vein, is semantically equivalent to either of the above: ***“Hey, {name}, I need a sanity check”***. Strictly speaking, a request for a sanity check (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check)) is simply asking whether there is any *obvious* problem with the idea/code, but the actual usage tends to be closer to that of the other two phrases.

Comment: Good differentiation of format usages. I liked Sherlock's "Mrs Hudson's taken my skull."

Comment: This answer / phrase highlights the critical difference between "rubber ducking" and [active listening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_listening).

Comment: Thanks - all 3 of those are useful to me! Although I may try to start popularizing the other phrase, "rubber duck," in my workplace just because I personally find it more colorful and interesting, which allows it to keep more specific connotations as well.

Comment: I like "rubber duck" best, too - but beware the particularly humor-impaired or the offense kleptomaniacs; they'll take it as demeaning or insulting.

Answer (score 4):

Our office used to call this the "nodding dog syndrome" after the toy once found in a lot of British cars.

Amazon: [Lovely Shaking Head Nodding Dog Car Interior Decoration Ornament Pattern Random](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shaking-Nodding-Interior-Decoration-Ornament/dp/B01N6O2BG0/)

The advantage is that they do NOT ask questions that can derail your thoughts, but will always nod approvingly, encouraging you to keep talking.

While you might have to explain what you want to someone the first time you use this phrase it is clear you are asking them to perform a certain role not just engage in a standard discussion.

Comment: FWIW, the American name for such toy generically is 'bobble-head'.

Comment: I always think of a bobble-head as having the head on a spring, while a "nodding dog" has a loose attachment at the top of the neck so the movement is more side-to-side and less forward-&-back.  But that's probably just me ......

Answer (score 2):

You need someone to **listen to you thinking aloud**, which basically means that you do all the thinking and talking and the other is just creating an environment where thinking aloud can be done more comfortably.